# Game theory: Given a number N, decide the winner.

Tags: number-theory, combinations, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given a number $N$:

- Two people A and B subtracts a number **k**
  $\left(~0 < k < N,\ k\mid N~\right)$ alternatively from $N$.
- The one who cannot make a move loses the game.Provided that **A** always starts first, decide the winner.

Initially, I tried solving this problem using dynamic programming considering the fact that a state can be a winning one if it leads to at least one losing state. Also, a state is a losing one if all the states it goes to are winning. Checking for all the states didn't prove to be time efficient. After looking at the solutions I found that this problem boils down to checking whether **N** is odd or even. What I think is, one can say that if a state **X** is losing then $\mathbf{X + 1}$ $\left(\,\mbox{as}\ \mathbf{1\mid\left(\,X + 1\,\right)}\,\right)$ will always be a winning state but what if $\mathbf{X}$ is a winning state ?.

How can one prove that even states will always be winning and vice versa ?.

Comment: do you mean, each player subtracts a divisor of the number they have been handed?  (the way you wrote it, it seems like the player always subtracts a divisor of the fixed number $N$).

Comment: Assuming I have the rules right then:  Hint:  simple induction.

Comment: Hint: if $X$ is odd, then all its divisors are odd. Odd - Odd = ?

Comment: @lulu: A player subtracts divisors of the number he has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note a few things:

**1) If you are passed an even number, you can not be made to lose in that turn.**

This is because $N = 2m > 1$ and $1|N$ so you can pass $N -1$.

**2) If you are passed an odd number, then either a) you are forced to lose if $N =1$ or b) you are forced to pass an even number. And your opponent cannot be made to lose in the next turn.**

a) if $N =1$ you can't do anything.

b) if $N > 1$ but $N$ is odd so if $k|N$ then $k$ is odd and you must pass $N -k$ which is an odd minus an odd must be even.

**3) if you are passed an even you can make it so that you are passed an even the next turn (if there *is* a next turn).**

Just pass the $N-1$.  That will be odd and your opponent must pass you an even by 2). (or the opponent must lose if you passed a $1$).  [If you have a larger odd $k$ that divides $N$ you can pass $N -k$ which will also be odd.  That will speed the game up.]

**4) The game is finite and must end.**

You are passed a finite $N$ and you pass an $1 \le N - k < N$ that is smaller.  There are only a finite number (maximum $N$) turns that can be taken.

...... so ......

So if you are passed an even you need not lose that turn or, by induction, any other turn.  If you are passed an odd you might lose but you can not make your opponent lose.  All games must end.

Therefore (if both players play the best strategy) player $A$ will lose if the first $N$ is odd.  Player $A$ will win if the first $N$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2^a\cdot d$ where $d$ is an odd number. We have two cases.

1) If $a>0$ then $n$ is even and if the player subtracts $0< d<n$ (or any divisor of $d$) then we obtain $n-d=(2^a-1)\cdot d$ which is odd.

2) If $a=0$ then $n$ is odd and any divisor $k$ is odd too. So for any move $0<k<n$ the new number $n-k$ is even.

Therefore we may conclude that the initial number $N$ is winning for the first player if and only if $N$ is even.

Comment: @Aditya pratap singh Any further doubts?

Comment: @ RobertZ  :Now, I can see the things clearly but initially wasn't able to conclude the answer based on the above two cases.

Answer (score 1):

From an even state, you can always get to an odd state (by subtracting $1$), but from an odd state you can only get to an even state, because the only divisors of an odd number are odd, and odd minus odd is even.  (The game ends at the odd number $1$, since there is no integer $k$ between $0$ and $1$.)

Remark:  For a nontrivial variant, you might take a look at a game I came up with some years ago which, for lack of a better name, I call [Factor Subtractor](http://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g10gift/Cipra_Barry-Factor_Subtractor.pdf).  The [sequence of starting numbers](https://oeis.org/A208980) for which there is a winning opening move has no apparent regularity.

Answer (score -1):

If $N=2$, then the second player, **B** wins the game.

---

---

Lets set some notations. Given $N$ as described above.
Let $a_1=N$.

First state:

Assume that **A** chooses in the first state $\alpha_1$.
Then let $b_1:=a_1-\alpha_1$.
Assume that **B** chooses in the first state $\beta_1$.
Then let $a_2:=b_1-\beta_1$.

Second state:

Assume that **A** chooses in the second state $\alpha_2$.
Then let $b_2:=a_2-\alpha_2$.
Assume that **B** chooses in the second state $\beta_2$.
Then let $a_3:=b_2-\beta_2$.

.......
.......

$i$-th state:

Assume that **A** chooses in the $i$-th state $\alpha_i$.
Then let $b_i:=a_i-\alpha_i$.
Assume that **B** chooses in the $i$-th state $\beta_i$.
Then let $a_{i+1}:=b_i-\beta_i$.

---

---

In all other cases, i.e., $2 \leq N$, the first player, **A** wins the game.

Let $k$ be the least natural number, which does'nt divides $N$, i.e.

$k:=min\{n \in \mathbb{N} : N-1 \geq n \nmid N  \}$.

## The strategy for the first player in the $i$-th state, is to choose the unique element $\alpha_i \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k-1\}$ such that $b_i:=a_i-\alpha_i$ is divisible by $k$.

---

---

Let $k$ be the least natural number, which does'nt divides $N$, i.e.

$k:=min\{n \in \mathbb{N} : N-1 \geq n \nmid N  \}$.

[Notice that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \nmid N \}$ is not empty.

Notice that $N-1 \nmid N$, since N is greater than $1$.]

Also notice that for every $t \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k-1\}$ we have that:

$t\mid N$, by definition.

---

---

In $i$-th state the first player, **A** subtracts

the unique element $\alpha_i \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k-1\}$;

such that $b_i:=a_i-\alpha_i$ is divisible by $k$.

[By the euclid's algorithm, **A** can be able to do such a move.]

---

---

Now it's the second player turn.

We claim that **B** could not win.

Suppose on contrary that **B** could win, so he/she must choose the whole remaining number; i.e. $b-i$

which means that the remaining number $b_i$ divides $N$.

On the other hand, $k \mid b_i$;
since **A** makes the remaining number divisible by $k$.

So we have: $k \mid b_i \mid N$,

so by the property of transitivity of division we have

that $k \mid N$, which contradicts the definition of $k$.

---

---

## Example

$N=60$.

In this case $k:=7$ is the least number which does not divides $60$.

The remainder of $a_1=60$ by $7$; is equal to $4$, so **A** subtracts $4$, and $56=b_1=a_1-\alpha_1=60-4$ is divisible by $7$.

Now it is the second player's turn for example he chooses $15$,
$41=a_2=b_1-\beta_1=56-15$ has the remainder equal to $6$ module $7$, so **A** subtracts $6$, and $35=b_2=a_2-\alpha_2=41-6$ is divisible by $7$.

Now again, it is the second player's turn for example he chooses $5$,
$30=a_3=b_2-\beta_2=35-5$ has the remainder equal to $2$ module $7$, so **A** subtracts $2$, and $28=b_3=a_3-\alpha_3=30-2$ is divisible by $7$.

Now again, it is the second player's turn for example he chooses $20$,
$8=a_4=b_3-\beta_3=28-20$ has the remainder equal to $1$ module $7$, so **A** subtracts 1, and $7=b_4=a_4-\alpha_4=8-1$ is divisible by $7$.

Now again, it is the second player's turn for example he chooses $2$,
$5=a_5=b_4-\beta_4=7-2$ has the remainder equal to $5$ module $7$, so **A** subtracts $5$; $0=b_5=a_5-\alpha_5=5-5$, and he wins the game.

## Notice that every integer like $a$ which is divisible by $7$ could not divide $60$, since $7$ does not divides $60$.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you are assuming the players always subtract a factor of the *original* number.  That's an interesting variant, but fairly clearly not what the OP intended.  (Also, why do you say that $N=2$ is winning for the second player?  The first player can subtract $1$, leaving the second player with no move.)

Comment: Yes my strategy is exactly that. I'v proved that in this strategy the first player wins. But what do you mean by "always subtract a factor of the original number"; Is'nt the condition of our problem?!!

Comment: the OP fairly clearly means that each player must subtract a proper divisor of the *current* number.  E.g., if you start at $60$ and player A subtracts $5$, leaving $55$, then player B's options are to subtract $1$, $5$, or $11$.

Comment: Additional note:  your variant also appears to assume that the players must choose a proper divisor of the original numbers that leaves a *non-negative* difference when subtracted from the current number, so that the game ends at $0$.  The OP's intended version always ends at $1$.

Comment: Nonsense.  If $N > 2$ and $N$ is odd then $A$ will lose.  Example.  $N= 3$.  By your strategy A will subtract $1$ and give B $2$.  So $B$ will subtract $1$ and give A $1$ and $B$ will win.  If $N= 63$ then by your strategy $k = 2$ so A will play on and give $62$.  Then $B$ will play subtract $31$ and give $31$.  By your strategey $A$ will play $1$ and give $30$.  Then $B$ will play $15$ and give $15$.  So A subracts 1 and give 14.  B subtracts and gives 7.  A gives 6, B gives 3.  A gives 2.  B gives 1 and wins.

Comment: " (Also, why do you say that N=2 is winning for the second player? The first player can subtract 1, leaving the second player with no move.) "  Except player A could play 7 and get -6.  Then B could play 7 and get -13 etc.

Comment: I let 1 in the legal cases, my legal cases are 1,2,3,...

Comment: But your legal cases is 2,3,4,5, ....